Quantlib Heston MC Discrepancy between methods
I am a newbie at Quantlib (not finance) and am trying to price with the Heston model. I have implemented two different ways to verify the correctness of the Heston path generation to use in a custom pricing framework. However, I find different prices, where the manual path generation method price is higher than the direct MCEngine method (and analytical)
The Heston process is setup as:
    today = ql.Date().todaysDate()
risk_free_quote = ql.SimpleQuote(r)
riskFreeTS = ql.YieldTermStructureHandle(
    ql.FlatForward(today, ql.QuoteHandle(risk_free_quote), ql.Actual365Fixed())
)
dividendTS = ql.YieldTermStructureHandle(ql.FlatForward(today, dividends, ql.Actual365Fixed()))

initialValue = ql.QuoteHandle(ql.SimpleQuote(s0))
hestonProcess = ql.HestonProcess(
    riskFreeTS, dividendTS, initialValue, v0, kappa, theta, eta, rho
)

Using MCHestonEngine this price is then simply:
    engine = ql.MCEuropeanHestonEngine(hestonProcess, rng, steps, requiredSamples=numPaths)

# Option parameters (European Call Option)
strikePrice = K
optionType = ql.Option.Call

# Option settings
maturity_days = int(T*365)
exerciseDate = today + ql.Period(maturity_days, ql.Days)
exercise = ql.EuropeanExercise(exerciseDate)
payoff = ql.PlainVanillaPayoff(optionType, strikePrice)

# Option object
option = ql.VanillaOption(payoff, exercise)
option.setPricingEngine(engine)

# Calculate option prices and extract paths
optionPrice = option.NPV()

Using manual price estimation from the paths:
    times = ql.TimeGrid(T, time_steps)
dimension = heston_process.factors()

rng = ql.GaussianRandomSequenceGenerator(
    ql.UniformRandomSequenceGenerator(dimension * time_steps, ql.UniformRandomGenerator()))
seq = ql.GaussianMultiPathGenerator(heston_process, list(times), rng, False)


spot_paths = []
vol_paths = []

for i in range(numPaths):
    sample_path = seq.next()
    values = sample_path.value()

    spot, vol = values

    spot_paths.append([x for x in spot])
    vol_paths.append([x for x in vol])

value = np.mean(np.maximum(spot[:, -1] - K, 0))

For example when I run this with say 100,000 paths with
S0 = 100  # Initial stock price
        K = 100  # Strike price
        T = 1  # Time to maturity (1 year)
        r = 0.05  # Risk-free interest rate
        kappa = 2.0  # Rate of mean reversion
        theta = 0.02  # Long-run variance
        sigma = 0.3  # Volatility of volatility
        rho = -0.7  # Correlation between stock and variance processes
        v0 = 0.04  # Initial variance

I get:
Price from paths generation: 9.731405080937167
Price from MCEngine: 9.283910498507433
Analytical Price: 9.26465992920577
There is obviously some small detail I am doing wrong with the TimeGrid but I can't figure out what exactly. Any help appreciated.

At a quick glance it looks like you're not discounting the payoff.

bingo! I was so obsessed with the small quantlib details I forgot the most basic part of pricing.
